# How do I get an NSManaged Object ID from an array and delete it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an array of NSManagedObject called coreTasks. I want to be able to whenever I remove an object from the array to be able to remove the object from my coreData entity because at launch of the application the coredata entity will populate my array so my contextualaction below is not permanently deleting the object.

```
    func deleteAction(at: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let deleteActionImage = UIImage(named: "Delete")?.withTintColor(.white)
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive , title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
        
        coreTasks.remove(at: at.row)
        self.homeTableView.deleteRows(at: [at], with: .automatic)
        completion(true)
    }
    action.image = deleteActionImage
    action.backgroundColor = Colors.reddelete
    return action
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the object ID, just delete the record in the context and save the context.

```
func deleteAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let deleteActionImage = UIImage(named: "Delete")?.withTintColor(.white)
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive , title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let objectToDelete = coreTasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.homeTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        context.delete(objectToDelete)
        try? context.save()

        completion(true)
    }
    action.image = deleteActionImage
    action.backgroundColor = Colors.reddelete
    return action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete an object you have to call this method:

```
func deleteCoreTasks(withUUID uuid: UUID) {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CoreTasks> = CoreTasks.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "uuid", uuid as CVarArg)
        
        do {
            
            let coreTasks = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            
            if let coreTask = coreTasks.first {
                 context.delete(coreTask)
            }
            
            try context.save()
            
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    }
```

1. First, you have to find your object in your DB. In the method I
   wrote I'm using an UUID, but you can find that with in other ways
   (depends on your model).
2. Second, delete the object.
3. Third, save the context (important!)

Comment: My question is how to get the ID of an object to be able to delete it xd